# Unable to decrypt the password throws javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, aes

In JDK 1_7, I am trying to decrypt the encrypted password.From the result set (rs2),encrypted password is passed to a string variable and later on calling the decrypt method and passed the string 'p_password' and key.While decrypting the password system throws "*javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded*"
Can someone please advise on how to resolve this problem?
// Encrypted password retrieving from result set

```
 String key = "Blowfish";
 String p_password = rs2.getString("USER_PASSWORD");
 EncryptDecrypt encryptdecrypt = new EncryptDecrypt();  
 String p_decryptedPassword = encryptdecrypt.decrypt(p_password, key);
```

//EncryptDecrypt class

```
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    public class EncryptDecrypt {   
    public static String encrypt(String strClearText, String strKey) throws Exception{
            String strData="";

            try {
                SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
                Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
                byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());
                strData=new String(encrypted);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
            return strData;
        }

        public static String decrypt(String strEncrypted,String strKey) throws Exception{
            String strData=null;

            try {
                byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
                SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
                Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec, ivspec);
                byte[] decrypted=cipher.doFinal(strEncrypted.getBytes());
                strData= new String(decrypted); 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
            return strData;

        }


    }
```

Comment: I was trying to write an answer, but now I'm presuming that this is a test, because absolutely nothing is correct in this answer. The key generation directly from a plaintext password, IV handling, ECB and CBC mixup, the encoding of the ciphertext, the use of platform encoding, the use of the ancient Blowfish cipher with short block size, the exception handling... If you would need to write a book on how not to perform encryption then you would come pretty close; I propose you replace Blowfish with DES and the code would be perfect. Do a crypto course & start again.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Agreed, as this is my first attempt on encryption/ decryption. I have been trying on this for last three days, anyway I will try on DES as you said

Comment: The use of DES was a joke, as Blowfish is old and not recommended anymore (by the author Bruce himself) but DES is completely insecure. by the way, I'm contemplating to write a book about crypto for developers, this post was rather useful - but don't worry, I won't quote :)